# Determine if a visitor is not a bot/crawler with Smarty

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

How can we determine if a visitor accessing our website is not a bot or crawler using Smarty's v3 template (.tpl) file system?

In PHP for example a simple solution would be:

```
if (!preg_match('/bot|proxy|crawl|slurp|spider/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){

}
```

Is there any simple way to do this right into the smarty.net's template file?

Comment: With 100% accuracy it's not possible

Comment: try using captcha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smarty is the template engine, its purpose to do presentation, however, it can also do logic, which then, it makes less sense and makes you code more dependent, thus harder to change.

What you could do?

The best solution, is to assign the template with processed logic to Smarty's variable, example:

**PHP:**

```
$smarty->assign('is_bot', preg_match('/bot|proxy|crawl|slurp|spider|^$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])));
```

**Template:**

```
{if !$is_bot}
    <!-- non bot stuff -->
{/if}
```

Other than above, you could also create [Smarty Plugin](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.writing.tpl). It's easy to do. Example:

**Smarty Plugin:**

```
<?php
function smarty_function_isBot(array $params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template)
{
    return preg_match('/bot|proxy|crawl|slurp|spider|^$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']));
}
?>
```

**Template:**

```
{isBot}
```

Using conditions

```
{if isBot}
    <!-- non bot stuff -->
{/if}
```